# Reverse look-up with related name

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Suppose these models:

```
class Person (models.Model):
    pass
```

and

```
class Marriage (models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='person')
    person_2 = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='person_2')
```

How can I filter persons through the ID of a Marriage field (e.g. the ID)? That is, my goal is to do something like Person.objects.filter(marriage__id=32). I understand that the related name has some role there, but for example Person.objects.filter(person_2__marriage__id=32) doesn't seem to work either.

Thank you!

Comment: There is no more `marriage` name to access after you misnomered the related name like that. `Person.objects.filter(person_2_id=32)` will work.

Comment: I just realized my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: DO you have extra fields on the Marriage model?

Comment: Yes, a few more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd say you can remove the `related_name` and use the following construct:

```py
mariage = Mariage.objects.get(id=32)
person = mariage.person
person2 = mariage.person_2
```

However, it depends on what you're trying to achieve. With something like:

```py
class Marriage (models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='mariage_person_1')
    person_2 = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='mariage_person_2')
```

You should be able to run queries such as:

```py
from django.db.models import Q
query = Q(mariage_person_1=32) | Q(mariage_person_2=32)
persons = Person.objects.filter(query)
```